# Leaflet map.on(click) event isn't triggered on the marker which has its own onclick event

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a marker which has its own onclick event

```
marker.on("click", function(e){ 
        let popup = e.target.getPopup();
        .... // fill with content when clicked
```

and a map event

```
map.on("click",function(e){
  console.log(e.latlng);
}
```

Clicking where the marker is placed triggers only the marker event (popup's being opened). Is there any possibility to trigger both events?

Comment: That should be the default with the event bubbling logic introduced in Leaflet 1.0.0. What version of Leaflet are you using?

Comment: I have the latest stable version: 1.6.0

Comment: According to that example posted some time ago https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5313 such a behavior is default for markers.

Comment: ...and that behaviour was changed back in https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4883 . I think you now have enough information to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
bubblingMouseEvents: true
```

in marker options. Then a mouse event on this marker will trigger the same event on the map (unless L.DomEvent.stopPropagation is used).